# Yii2 correct rules for update unique database fields

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii2

I'm trying to update row with 3 unique columns. Rules allow to insert first record but when I'm trying to update row Yii throws error: `The combination [unique column names] has already been taken.`

Database: `MySQL`, Yii version: `2.0.35`

Successfully inserted first time:
[image]
Next attempts lead to errors:

[image]

Table structure:
[image]

Rules:
[image]

Thank you for help!

Comment: Looks like you don't update the row but again trying to insert it. Make sure the row to be updated is fetched from the database and not instantiated as a new active record with the same ID.

Comment: Yeah that advice helped me to search issue in right direction. If you add this reply as answer I'll mark it as correct answer.